# Upgrading Qt Version for use on KDE distros

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, qt, kde-plasma-5

I was wondering if it's possible to upgrade the QT version used by a distro such as Kubuntu to satisfy dependencies that for example some widgets might have. So for example use Qt 5.9 with Kubuntu 16.04 systemwide to be able to run widgets that might depend on them, when it only ships with 5.5.1.

I've tried updating the KDE plasma - that didn't work (broken display), though I'm not even sure about the relationship between them.

I've also tried doing this

[How to update Qt from 5.5.1 to 5.9.5 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062046/how-to-update-qt-from-5-5-1-to-5-9-5-on-ubuntu-16-04)

but it doesn't seem to work for widgets (?) - `qmake -v` and 
`qmake -qt=qt5 -v` gave me the correct output, but under System Info my Qt Version was still being reported as 5.5.1.

Comment: Qt isn't like a stand-alone application.  There are endless dependency and compatibility relationships with something like Qt.  Manually installing a newer version is likely to create problems.  If the newer version is available in the Ubuntu repository, you can try installing it with the package manager, and that stands a good chance of identifying everything else that would also need to be updated.  Any other approach is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you! Why didn't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stand-alone application, it is common to be able to "manually" install it in Linux.  By "manually", I mean other than using the package manager to install it from the distro's repository.  That might be just downloading and unarchiving the package in a particular location, downloading a deb or rpm package from a website and having the package manager install it, or adding a PPA and having the package manager do the honors.

The application may have some dependencies, and the package manager can typically handle that.  If you run into trouble, it's usually because the package you're loading wants a specific version of something like a code library, which is also used by something else you have installed, and the something else needs a different version.

Qt isn't like a stand-alone application. It's an application framework and widget toolkit for graphical user interfaces.  It's a system by which a lot of different software allows you to interact with the computer.  So it's an integral part of a lot of stuff, and there are endless dependency and compatibility relationships.

Linux Mint is basically Ubuntu.  Mint decided to [drop support for KDE](https://itsfoss.com/linux-mint-drops-kde/) because of its basis on Qt.  It took too much resources to integrate Qt into Ubuntu.  So you can imagine that it isn't simply a matter of downloading and installing Qt.  Even Kubuntu is an effort separate from Ubuntu.  It's a "labor of love" by some developers.  Many of that team actually went to KDE to work on KDE's Neon distro, and there was a question as to whether Kubuntu would survive (so far, it has).

If you have a lot of Linux skill and intimate familiarity with Qt, Ubuntu, and KDE, it could be a good project and learning experience to manually upgrade Qt.  Otherwise, it would make sense to just piggyback on the work of the Kubuntu maintainers.  When they get the newer version of Qt integrated into Kubuntu, it will be part of the update package.

If you need to try to upgrade it yourself before that, and the newer Qt version is available in the Ubuntu repository, you can try installing it with the package manager.  That stands a good chance of identifying everything else that would also need to be updated. Any other approach is asking for trouble.